# RDP Credentials Manager hangs when NFC pad has been connected

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, smartcard

I'm struggling with a problem with RDP in a local domain environment.

Everything usually works perfectly, and I can remote into any client or server within the domain.  However, I'm working on a project which utilises an NFC pad, and I'm sure this is the cause of the problem.

The issue is that, after "Credentials Manager" is opened to connect to the remote device, it hangs for several minutes after entering the credentials.  Eventually the connection will be established and it all works perfectly from then on.

The same issue also happens if I press the cancel button instead of entering credentials, except of course that the connection is not established.

Removing the NFC pad does not help, but removing the NFC pad and restarting my computer gets rid of the problem completely.  Attaching the NFC pad again brings back the problem again until the next restart.

I've attempted the following:

- Opening RDP first, and ensuring that "Smart cards or Windows Hello for Business" is unticked.
- Using the NFC Pad in each available USB port
- Putting NFC devices on the pad when attempting to connect
- Set a Group Policy in Computer Configuration > Windows Components > Smart Card > Turn on Smart Card Plug and Play Service = Disabled

None of the above has worked and I'm out of ideas.  As I said, I'm sure it's related to having the NFC pad connected as I can replicate the issue at any time by connecting it, and I can repeat the issue on different computers to.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Card readers are peculiar.  In our enterprise, discovered the following:
1)  Laptop reader works most of the time

2)  But .... it works to log onto the laptop, but fails when using RDP.  Go figure.

3)  So I use the reader on the keyboard.  It works with RDP and laptop sign-on.

4)  Until recently -- so had to use a portable reader via USB.  Works pretty well

5)  But -- once in a while, it doesn't.  Have a 2nd portable reader and it works

6)  But ... some systems time-out before the credentials are exchanged in an RDP session.

Lesson learned:  Multiple readers